# Finding examples of functions with these properties.

Tags: complex-analysis, functions

I have this question regarding functions $f:\mathbb{C}\mapsto \mathbb{C}$, asking me to show no function exists such that it possesses both i) $f(z)^2=z$ for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$, and ii) $f(zw)=f(z)f(w)$ for all $z,w \in \mathbb{C}$, but that many functions exist with either property.

I managed to prove no such function exists, and that many may have property ii, but I can't think of anything that has property i except for (the invalid function) square roots! Can I please have some examples of such functions?

Comment: For i) you could take the square root on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{R}^-$ and there you just define it the way you need it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's wrong with square roots? You don't ask for a *holomorphic* function. Take for example
$$f(z) = f(re^{it}) = \sqrt{r}e^{it/2}$$
where you choose $t$ such that $-\pi < t \le \pi$. By changing the choice of $t$ you get lots of examples, none of them holomorphic on the whole of $\mathbb C$ of course.

Comment: you aren't even continuous ;)

Comment: No, it can't be done continously either.

Comment: @mrf Well, now I've realised that I didn't manage the proof I thought I had! (I managed to show no -continuous- function exists..!) as the proof was essentially only square-roots satisfy both properties, and this is not allowed. The question doesn't specify continuous though; but still, if square-roots are allowed, then it will have both properties which is apparently not possible..

Comment: @FireGarden No, my example doesn't satisfy the second property: $f(-i)f(-i) \neq f(-1)$.